# My Developer Account cannot be activated because I used a relative's credit card

Tags: app-store-connect

So now I have an "identity cannot be verified" message whenever I activate it from the activation code Apple gave me via email.

Is there anything I can do about this or is my $99 "doomed"?

Comment: email apple support. they should be able to help you.

Answer (score 4):

From the [iOS Developer Program Support](http://developer.apple.com/support/ios/purchase-and-next-steps.html):

> If I enroll as an Individual in the Standard program can I use someone else’s credit card to purchase the Program?
>
> The billing information provided for
>   the purchase must exactly match the
>   Program enrollment information. If
>   this information does not match your
>   enrollment will be delayed and you
>   will be asked to provide a notarized
>   copy of a government issued
>   identification.

I would contact support and ask them what to do next.

Answer (score 2):

I have used other individual's credit cards for this purpose.  You should have no problem after phoning Developer Support Hotline http://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.html

Occasionally it gets stuck for no apparent reason that Apple could explain.  Happened to a client of mine yesterday.  We phoned and all was made well in minutes.

Comment: what will I tell them when I phone them?

Comment: Tell them your identity cannot be verified but all your details are complete.  They will be able to see if there are any discrepancies on your account. Normally they wave a magic wand and it proceeds.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to get in touch with Apple and perhaps they will ask your relative to call, because they will want to make sure that you didn't "steal" the credit card. Other than that, you're not "doomed" in any way.